# leaflet invert when there are multiple polygons

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, polygon

I'm using this library to invert leaflet layers.

https://github.com/ebrelsford/Leaflet.snogylop

This works perfectly when there is only one polygon. But when are there are multiple polygons, the invert applies for each and every polygon so it overlaps resulting invert feature applies on top of each polygon. Like the image attached below.

[image]

When trying on a single polygon it works perfectly.[image]

How can i fix this issue when multiple polygons are there.

```
function handleJson(data) {
  var selectedArea = L.geoJson(data, {
    invert: true,
    worldLatLngs: [
      L.latLng([90, 360]),
      L.latLng([90, -180]),
      L.latLng([-90, -180]),
      L.latLng([-90, 360])
  ]
  });
  selectedArea.addTo(lmap);
  lmap.fitBounds(selectedArea.getBounds());
}
```

PS:

[image]

**poly.toGeoJSON()**

```
{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[null,null],[null,null]]],[[[null,null],[null,null]]],[[[null,null],[null,null]]],[[[null,null],[null,null]]],[[[null,null],[null,null]]],[[[null,null],[null,null]]],[[[null,null],[null,null]]]]}}
```

**multipolyCoords**

```
[[[[{"lat":35.41263883,"lng":63.02502113},{"lat":35.41251986,"lng":63.02571771},{"lat":35.41329411,"lng":63.02584793},{"lat":35.41378402,"lng":63.02643689},{"lat":35.41402821,"lng":63.02723164},{"lat":35.41342648,"lng":63.02885513},{"lat":35.41342962,"lng":63.02891854},{"lat":35.4100508,"lng":63.02941312},
.....................
]]]],"_initHooksCalled":true
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a MultiPolygon out of the polygons.

Try this (I'm assuming that you only have polygons in `data`):

```
var layers = L.geoJSON(data);

var multipolyCoords = [];
layers.eachLayer((l)=>{
    if(l instanceof L.Polygon){
        multipolyCoords.push(l.getLatLngs())
    }
})

var poly = L.polygon(multipolyCoords);

var selectedArea = L.geoJson(poly.toGeoJSON(), {
    invert: true,
    worldLatLngs: [
      L.latLng([90, 360]),
      L.latLng([90, -180]),
      L.latLng([-90, -180]),
      L.latLng([-90, 360])
  ]
  });
```

Comment: I'm getting an error as "Uncaught Error: Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, NaN)"

Comment: Can you please share data and create a jsfiddle?

Comment: i've attached a screen shot of my console, if it helps.

Comment: please add the output of `console.log(JSON.stringify(poly.toGeoJSON()))`

Comment: I updated it in the question. Coordinates are having null values. So it's the issue. But not sure why it's getting the null values.